# How to change the colour theme in wordpress site already existing

Tags: wordpress

I am trying out wordpress, never did anything with it. I have to change the colors of an already existing website. When I select a different theme and press "apply", it doesn't work. The colors and the theme does not change.
Someone can tell me how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about programming.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Every theme is different. There's really no way we can help you.

Comment: How is that rude? We cannot help you with what you posted. It's too vague and what you're asking isn't programming. I didn't down vote the question and gave you the reason why it should be closed.

Comment: As per Stackoverflow TOS. `Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based` may be **[closed by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)** until they are improved.

Comment: `To maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Be sure to **[Be on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to `allow others to reproduce the problem`. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: If you continue to respond unkindly, you will most likely get your account closed. I understand you are trying to learn. This particular question cannot be answered. We do not have the information to help you. We don't know what theme you are using. There are 1000s of themes. You have only mentioned that you "selected a different theme and pressed 'apply'". That pretty much takes it out of the programming realm at this point, since you are asking about a UI interaction and have not posted code. We're not unkind, we really cannot help. A good solution is to ask the theme developer.

Answer (score 0):

The colors of the website does not depend on the theme which is installed.
You can change the colors by adding css and selecting global tags such as body or whatever. You could use the Custom CSS & JS plugin to do that.

Comment: This is better as a comment instead of an answer. Some themes allow for "color themes" which the user can select and apply without any CSS/JS.